# Not seeing Content along with Size Column and not seeing Latency along with Time column in Latest Chrome Developer tools? How can i enable these?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app, chromium

I want to ensure my application is doing GZIP Compression. to check that i need to compare Size/Content ration in chrome dev tools. But i am not seeing Content in Size Column and not seeing Latency in Time column in the Latest Chrome Developer tools? How can i enable these?

Comment: Can't you simply look at the response headers of the request in devtools and check whether `gzip` is present?

Comment: If i want to compare the acutal size vs compressed size, where can i see in the developer tools?

Comment: I still see the Content-Length column in the right click menu of the column header in Chrome dev 46.0.2471.2